# How to reverse a list - scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

```lisp
(define (oddrev ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) ls)
          ((null? (cdr ls)) ls)
          (else (cons (car ls) (oddrev (cdr (cdr ls)))))))
```

I have a scheme that returns odd array elements but I want to reverse the list at the end.
How would I do that??

Answer (score 2):

The trivial solution is to add a layer of indirection:

```
(define (oddrev-helper ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) ls)
          ((null? (cdr ls)) ls)
          (else (cons (car ls) (oddrev-helper (cdr (cdr ls)))))))

(define (oddrev ls) (reverse (oddrev-helper ls)))
```

This looks wasteful, but is much more efficient than repeatedly appending a singleton list at the end.

But if you have encountered the way to transform a recursive process to an iterative by way of an accumulator and tail recursion, you will have noticed that list procedures have a habit of producing the result in reverse.

You can take advantage of this if you actually want the result in reverse.

```
(define (oddrev-helper ls acc)
  (cond ((null? ls) acc)
        ((null? (cdr ls)) (cons (car ls) acc))
        (else (oddrev-helper (cdr (cdr ls)) (cons (car ls) acc)))))

(define (oddrev ls) (oddrev-helper ls '()))
```

Answer (score 0):

By tail recursion (and leaving out the usual `reverse`ing at the end when returning.

```
(define (oddrev ls (acc '()))
    (cond ((or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls))) acc)
          (else (oddrev (cdr (cdr ls)) (cons (car ls) acc)))))
```

Or by standard higher order functions:

```
(define (oddrev ls)
  (reverse (filter odd? ls)))
```

Try out:

```
(oddrev '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; '(5 3 1)
```

change the line

```
(cond ((or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls))) acc)
```

to:

```
(cond ((or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls))) (reverse acc))
```

to let it return in the input order: `'(1 3 5)`